# Problem with scanf in C program to input elements of a list individually and output them

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm trying to make a program that inputs elements into a list separately, but somehow it only runs until the second element and I have no idea why.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n; 
    int arr[n];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        printf("%d", arr[x]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
5
1
2
12
--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.99 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is what I originally got. I tried adding a `\\n` character in the second `scanf`, but it got me this.

```
5
1
2
3
12
\--------------------------------
Process exited after 5.1 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: When you define the array `arr`, what is the value of `n`? Remember that variable definitions aren't done retroactively, they happen in the exact order you coded them. Which means the value of `n` at that point in the running of the program will be *indeterminate* (it might help to look at the value as random or garbage). Not until after the array is created you read an actual value into `n`. Simple solution: Switch place of the `scanf` call and the array definition.

Comment: @Vien Nguyen: What Some programmer dude is trying to tell you is that your program exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  STRONG SUGGESTION: Use your debugger.  Look at your variables as the program executes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay I think I got it, but there's now a new problem. For some reason the second scanf works one more time than expected, but the elements input stay the same as expected.
'''
4
1
2
3
4
5
1 2 3 4
--------------------------------
Process exited after 4.212 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
'''
I needed to input four elements, but somehow the scanf ran 5 times but still return the result of 4 elements.

Comment: @VienNguyen Let me ***guess***, you changed your `scanf` to `scanf("%d\n",...)`? Remove the newline from the format, it's not needed and will cause you more problems than it might solve (in this case it doesn't solve anything, only cause problems).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to enable **warnings**. If you use gcc use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` which will force you to remove all warnings otherwise the program will not compile.

When you compile your program you will get:

```
<source>:5:5: warning: 'n' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    5 |     int arr[n];
      |     ^~~
```

It means that you need to assign some value (for example by using `scanf`) first. Otherwise your code invokes undefined behaviour and the behaviour of your code cannot be predicted.

Also always check the result of `scanf`

```
int main(void){
    int n; 
    if(scanf("%d",&n) == 1)
    {
        int arr[n];
        
        for(int i = 0; i<n;i++){
            if(scanf("%d",&arr[i]) != 1) 
            {
                printf("Error scanning the value at index %d. Exiting\n", i);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x<n;x++){
            printf("%d",arr[x]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y481vcM1c

Comment: May I suggest `printf("%d\n", arr[x]);` ?

Comment: @chqrlie I was thinking about it but I was not sure if it was something OP wanted

Comment: I agree with "always enable full warnings".  For GCC, I'd encourage `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.  ALSO: I think it's VERY important to encourage developers to recognize that "the debugger is their friend".  To learn their debugger early, and to use it often.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I would discurage -pedantic as sticking to 40y standard makes no sense

Comment: It is unclear what the OP means by *I tried adding a `\\n` character in the second `scanf`*... adding a `\n` in the `scanf()` format requires extra input at the end but should not cause a ``\`` to appear in the output.

Comment: @paulsm4 Honestly I have no idea what I'm doing, I still haven't figured out how scanf fully works.